# How to convert PDF to TIFF [CCITT Group 4 Fax Encoding compression] in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tiff, image-compression

I am having a PDF file, I want to split the PDF file into an image in the file format of TIFF with the compression of CCITT Group 4 Fax Encoding. I have used pdf2image to convert into TIFF but I'm unable to convert into compression CCITT Group 4 Fax Encoding. I have used below code to convert into TIFF. Can you help me to compress the TIFF image in the CCITT Group 4 Fax Encoding format.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
TIFFPdf = convert_from_path(pdf, poppler_path=config['APPLICATION_LOCATION']['POPPLER_PATH'])

for img in TIFFPdf:
    img.save(str("{:04d}".format(imageId)) + '.tiff', 'TIFF')
    imageId += 1
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?